# Removing line breaks from Wikipedia API explaintext

Tags: javascript, python, wikipedia-api

My project uses python to call the wikipedia api and get the explaintext of a given page.  This text is then passed through flask to a javascript function to be shown on the page:

python:

```
return """<body onload="myscript(wikipedia_explaintext)"></body>"""
```

This usually works fine; however, sometimes I receive an error in the browser saying there was an unhandled line break.  I have tried correcting for this with the following code in python:

```
explaintext.replace('\n', '  ')
explaintext.replace('<br />', '  ')
explaintext.replace('<br>', '  ')
```

Again, this solves the problem most of the time; however, I seem to get the same error even after this handling.  Is there a way I can make the api request not return line breaks, or are there more replace statements I could make to solve this?

Comment: why have you used <b /> and not <b/>?

Comment: <b>is for bold. You probably wanted to use <br> and <br /> instead. And you could try explaintext.replace('\r', '  ')